# No Android SDK environment set for Kivy in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, python, ubuntu-12.04, android-sdk-tools, kivy

I've written a game for Android using Python and Kivy. I have downloaded `android-sdk-linux` and added its path to `.bashrc`. I've also cloned the `python-for-android` project to create an apk package of my program. But when I write the following command as instructed in the Kivy manual, I get an error:

```
./distubute.sh -m "kivy"

error:
    Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
    Check enviromnent
    No ANDROIDSDK environment set, abort
```

Why?

This is a picture of my `./android.sh` in `$android-sdk-linux/tools`:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: export ANDROIDSDK=/path/toyourandroidsdkfolder in your terminal then start your script again (in the same terminal window)

Comment: didn't work... :( but tnx

Comment: do you get the same error?

Comment: yes, exactly the same... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sincerely read the [docs](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/prerequisites/). In particular, pay attention to the environment variables you need to set mentioned at that bottom of the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i had forgotten to set the last two... And that was the problem... :) Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is a bit old, but:

```
export ANDROIDSDK="/path/to/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROIDNDK="/path/to/android-ndk-rY" #change Y here
export ANDROIDNDKVER=rY #same here
export ANDROIDAPI=X #change X here
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROIDNDK:$ANDROIDSDK/platform-tools:$ANDROIDSDK/tools
```

You have to change Y with the ndk version, and X with the API id.

You can add this to your ~/.bashrc.

It has solved the problem for me.